# Equivalent of PostGIS ST_LineSubstring in Python: GeoPandas/shapely or any alternatives

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a table in a db where I'm running some spatial queries but would like to move this to Python using GeoPandas, shapely etc.

Example:

```
ST_LineSubstring(geom, 0.005, 0.995)
```

[Which](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineSubstring.html)

> Computes the line which is the section of the input line starting and
> ending at the given fractional locations

Answer (score 5):

You can use [shapely.ops.substring](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.substring).

Usage:

> `shapely.ops.substring(geom, start_dist, end_dist[, normalized=False])`
>
> If the `normalized` arg is `True`, the distance will be interpreted as a fraction of the geometry’s length

Example:

```
from shapely.ops import substring

line_part = substring(geom, 0.005, 0.995, normalized=True)
```